# memory leak on delay job what's the better alternative on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I send mails with delay job worker.

The web app runs on EC2 instance with 2GB ram, somehow, the instance runs out of memory after booting a while

I guess the root cause is `delayed job`.

What's the good alternative for that.

Can I send the mail in `Thread.new` , therefore the user won't be blocked on sending email

here's how i run the servers and worker on boot

```
every :reboot do
  command " cd #{PROJECT} ; git pull origin develop "
  command " cd #{PROJECT} ; memcached -vv "
  command " cd #{PROJECT} ; bundle exec rake Delayed::Backend::Mongoid::Job.create_indexes "
  command " cd #{PROJECT} ; bundle exec rake jobs:work "
  command " cd #{PROJECT} ; bundle exec puma config/puma.rb"
  command " cd #{PROJECT} ; ruby app_periodic_tasks.rb"
end
```

Comment: Our apps had issues with memory, with time we upgraded them to better hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Try Sidekiq which seems much more solid.

Answer (score 0):

There are a solid number of [background processing tools](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs) in the Rails world and Sidekiq and Resque would be the top ones on that list for me.

I've been using Sidekiq for the last 3 years at work and it's a phenomenal tool that has done wonders for our large application.

We use it on two worker boxes: one handles assembling, building, storing, and sending e-newsletters and the other handles our application's members (uploading lists, parsing them, validating/verifying emails, and the like).

The assembly worker never runs into memory issues. Once or twice a month, I'll restart Sidekiq just to freshen it up but that's about it.

The member manager worker, which does far less than the assembly worker, requires its instance of Sidekiq to be restarted every few days. I end up with a Sidekiq worker/process that eats up a lot of memory and forces me to restart the service.

Sidekiq, however, isn't really the problem. It's my code ... there's a lot of I/O involved in managing members and I am certain that it's something I'm not doing right versus the tool itself.

So, long and short for me is this: your background tool is important but what you're doing in the code - related to the worker and elsewhere in an app - is more important (can also check to make sure memcached and caching aren't filling up your RAM, etc.).